# Python script works in command line, but not when running the .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm obviously still a beginner, but I'm creating a parsing file that goes through a text file, and builds a file that I need.

The logistics aren't as important as what's obviously happening.

```
import fileinput;
for lines in fileinput.FileInput("c:/manhattan.txt", inplace=1):    
    lines = lines.strip();                      
    if lines == '': continue;
    print(lines);


source = open('c:/manhattan.txt','r');
hrt = open('c:/test.hrt','w');
currentline = str(source.readline());  
currentline.lstrip();
workingline = '';                      
while currentline[0] != " ":
    if currentline[0].isdigit() == True:
        if currentline[0:3] == workingline[0:3] and len(workingline)<160:  
            workingline = workingline + currentline[4:7];          
            currentline = str(source.readline());   
            currentline.lstrip();
        else:
            hrt.write(('\x01' + 'LOC01LOC' + workingline).ljust(401,' ') +'\n');  
            workingline = currentline[0:7].replace(';','E');
            currentline = str(source.readline());
            currentline.lstrip();
    else:
        currentline = str(source.readline());
        currentline.lstrip();

hrt.write(('\x01'+'LOC50US1   A*').ljust(401,' ' +'\n');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
hrt.write(('\x02'+'LOCSUNSAT00:0023:5960 60             99990.00  0.00').ljust(401,' ')+'\n');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
hrt.write(('\x02'+'US SUNSAT00:0023:5960 60             99990.03  0.03').ljust(401,' ') +'\n');  
hrt.close();
source.close();
```

It works fine in the python command line, but when running the .py file it does't write the last three lines to the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: any error u r getting ?

Comment: 'other links\n'
    'discuss\n'
    'Like this site? We accept donations via PayPal.\n'
    ''
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    IndexError: string index out of range
    >>> hrt.write(('\x01'+'LOC50US1   A*').ljust(401,' ') +'\n');





    402
    >>> hrt.write(('\x02'+'LOCSUNSAT00:0023:5960 60                99990.00  0.00').lju
    st(401,' ') +'\n');




    402
    >>> hrt.write(('\x02'+'US SUNSAT00:0023:5960 60             99990.03  0.03').lju
st(401,' ') +'\n');
    402
    >>> hrt.close();
    >>> source.close();
    >>>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flushing the buffer before you close the file?

```
hrt.flush()
```

Comment: Ah, I see now you're actually getting an error when you run it.

Comment: There is an error, but it's still printing those 3 lines when ran in the python command line, but not when running the .py file.